# How to join a game as observer in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there an option to join your friends and observe the game from within (as in a replay only live) while they play? It used to be possible in SC1, is there a trick to it in SC2?

Comment: That sounds like it could give a player an incredible advantage.

Comment: This wasn't really possible without hacks in SC1 either, but there were observer maps that emulated a lot of the SC2 observer functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible unless you started the game as an observer.

When in the game lobby screen, the host can right click on a user, and say "make referee", they then become an observer for the game.

Any participants who join into the game lobby after it's full will automatically be observers / referees.

This procedure can also be used from a game save, if the participants are willing to go back out to the lobby to make this possible.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to make this for example in the single player campaign, right?

Comment: @Waylander Correct. No observation of the campaign is possible.